# Contao 4.4.x Remove Prefix .html from url

Tags: contao

How to remove (.html ) prefix from Contao url

Example : Currentl Url => http://example.com/startseite.html required url : http://example.com/startseite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following to your `config/config.yml` (`app/config/config.yml` prior to Contao 4.9).

```
contao:
    url_suffix: ''
```

After that, you need to clear and warmup the application cache, as with any configuration changes.

Comment: Following command can be used to clear the cache and perform said warmup: `vendor/bin/contao-console cache:clear --no-warmup` `vendor/bin/contao-console cache:warmup`